# How to remove default HTTP Headers from a SOAPReply node?

Tags: ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql, ibm-app-connect

Can I remove default HTTP headers from a **SOAPReply** node?

I tried to Overwrite it in ESQL and tried removing it using HTTPHeader node, I succeded in creating new HTTP Headers but failed to remove the default ones (for example "**Server: IBM App Connect Enterprise**").

The weird thing is that the same code works with HTTPReply node but not with **SOAPReply** node. Any suggestions?

My ESQL code:

```
SET OutputRoot.HTTPReplyHeader."Server" = 'MyDummyValue';
```

Output of HTTPReply node:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml
Server: MyDummyValue
```

Output of SOAPReply node:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml
Server: IBM App Connect Enterprise
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to override it in the Integration Server YAML file (**server.conf.yaml**) and it worked as expected for both HTTP and SOAP flows.

The value you need to override is:

```
/ResourceManagers/HTTP[S]Connector/ServerName
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked this page: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/app-connect/11.0.0?topic=node-local-environment-overrides-soapreply and I cannot see any local environment override that would suppress the default headers in a SOAPReply node.

Answer (score 0):

The `Server` header is in an internal list of headers that we don't allow you to set. I suspect it is to ensure that receiving clients know how to process the SOAP messages from ACE, we might have had a situation where it was overwritten and a client application failed, and it was added to the list.

Is there a particular reason why you need to modify the `Server` header?

Comment: The reason is that it's identified as a common security issue, please check [WSTG-INFO-02](https://owasp.org/www-project-web-security-testing-guide/latest/4-Web_Application_Security_Testing/01-Information_Gathering/02-Fingerprint_Web_Server) for reference.

Comment: that's a very valid point! I see you found a workaround in the YAML.  I'll raise this internally anyway, if you still think there should be a way to do so in-flow could you raise an "idea" here please: https://integration-development.ideas.ibm.com/ideas/project=APPC